# Tasks Assignment Underrated

Tags: career-development, new-job, project-management

I have recently joined a new company.

I was hired as a team leader which is is an analyst position, but I am wondering why I am not an analyst like the fellow team leaders. I was assigned a developer job with the other junior profiles.

A colleague faces the same case in a different project.

When I ask my manager, he says that I am too technical, and they think I would better suitable with developer role that contain technology I master?

The team leader status is HR affair, eventually.

Is it a good or bad sign that I was assigned a rare technology on my own, while I was expecting to work on core modules.

My manager said my learning aptitudes encouraged him to make these choices.

Is this normal?

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid that your post is very difficult to understand. So you were hired as a team leader, but your manager thought you were too technically oriented and essentially uses you as a developer instead?

Comment: Well, there is a difference between the company's hierarchy and project assignments. It's like I am a colonel but I am assigned a task like any low ranking soldier.

Comment: Analysts coincides with team leaders and technicians are developers.

Comment: Gotcha. Have you ever worked as a "colonel" before? Are you qualified?

Comment: No, this is my first time as a "colonel".

Comment: Thought so. Let me guess: you're a highly experienced developer who wants to move up into an analyst spot. You applied and were hired, but the new manager can't get over the fact that you're "a developer". Am I close?

Comment: Well, the manager told me he wanted me to become the technical reference in my region (on the long run). Deep down, it felt like he was trying to convince me for his own benefit. So I am not sure if he was honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that although you were hired as an analyst, your manager does not seem to think you're "right" for the role, and would like to relegate you to a technical position.

Presumably you are still being paid as an analyst, however, which raises a couple of questions:

1) Do you want to work as an analyst, or do the work of a developed?

2) Do you think the company will keep you on, seeing as you're overpaid?

Most job interviews provide candidates with a list of responsibilities. A job description, in other words. This is what you signed up to do, because presumably it's the direction in which you wish to take your career.

If what you're currently doing is not related to your job description then you have a problem. I would take that job description (maybe even a screenshot of the original job posting) and talk to your manager about it. Express a desire to stop working on development projects and do what you were actually hired to do.

I think that this situation poses a threat to you because you are not fulfilling the role which you were hired for. I would say that there's a very high probability of the company hiring another person to work as an analyst and letting you go, not to mention that you're not actually doing what you wanted to be doing.

Comment: Why do you think they did hire me?
We will go for a training abroad and so far they have prepared all the documents for me?

Comment: @halflife - HR, or whoever made the final decision to hire you, thought you were qualified. However, your direct boss, doesn't think you're a good fit for some reason. This might be because of some vibe he got from you when he met you, or maybe he's just playing political games (for example maybe he had someone he wanted to promote into the position, but his own boss hired you instead, so now he wants to make you look bad, and promote the other person). There's a lot of possibilities. I would push him to give you analyst responsibilities, or start looking for a new job ASAP.

Comment: The other possibility is that he just might not be convinced you're qualified for the job and you might be able to convince him. But if you try and can't seem to do it, understand that it might not be because you're not good enough but because he has other motives.

Comment: @AndreiROM the first day he saw me, the CEO told HR I don't know who this is? How come I didn't see him during the interview? Her response was something like "he lives in a fancy neighborhood" ... in a defensive way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's normal at all. You were hired for one thing and then given something else. You were basically lied to.

If it were me, I'd start looking elsewhere because clearly this company can't be trusted to keep its word. If they had concerns about your ability at an analyst level, they should have discussed that with you before telling you that you would be something else.

Employment is a two-way street. They've already shown you that they see it as a master-servant relationship.